# How to Set Markers Title

Tags: android, json, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

> How to set Markers UniqueId on markers title i have a ArrayList of uniqueId's and map on every markers title instead of "User Name"

```
 private void AddPointer() {
    try {
        //ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
        //TODO: remove previus markers
        if (marker != null) {
            mMap.clear();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remove", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
          int i=0;
        for (LatLng object : latLngList)

            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title((String) uniqueids.get(i)).position(object).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4)));
        i++;
        System.out.println(marker.getPosition() + "  Marker position.......");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // mMap.clear();
    }
}
```

> Here is my ArrayList

```
    private ArrayList uniqueids = new ArrayList();
   uniqueids.add(modelClass.getUniqueId().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll work only if length of `uniqueids` is same as `latLngList` otherwise it'll throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

```
int i=0;
for (LatLng object : latLngList) {
    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(uniqueids.get(i))
      .position(object)
      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4)));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: ELITE i implement it but it will always shows the 1st index of uniqueid's on every markers
I post the edited code

Comment: Check the for loop.. You are incrementing integer i after the loop.

Comment: Thanks sir you are great again thanssssssssssss issue resolved

Comment: In this code how i set the different default images on every Marker is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You have to create logic for it.